# How to configure a Bundle for workflow?

Tags: cme, workflow, bundles, blueprint

I missed a step in setting up Bundle Workflow and wanted to clarify a point I missed.

Setup:

1. Created Workflow Process definition in Visio and save to my schemas publication
2. Created Bundle Schema, setting it to the Workflow Process
3. Created a Bundle in my website publication, based on the Bundle Schema
4. Added items to Bundle

The Start Workflow Process button will not be enabled.

What's missing and how does the `Enable Workflow Process Associations in Shared Schemas and Structure Groups` work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Enable Workflow Process Associations in Shared Schemas and Structure Groups` lets us use Workflow Process definitions defined higher in the BluePrint in the current publication.

Without this checked in Publication Settings, only schemas set to local Workflow Process definitions are available.

We only need to check this in the Publication that contains the (Workflow) Bundle.

**Update**: I summarized this and the other basic steps in a [tutorial on SDL Tridion World](https://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2013/tutorials/setting-up-bundle-workflow.aspx).

Comment: I missed this small step in a demo (oops), but now hopefully no one else will. I marked this as a "community wiki"--feel free to add other basic setup steps for when the `Start Workflow` button should be enabled (e.g. only certain items can go in workflow).

Comment: Added a link to the related tutorial to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are some other optional settings like

- Dissolve the bundle when the workflow is finished.
- Components based in this schema are required to be in a bundle workflow.
- Pages in this structure group are required to be in a bundle workflow.

Also in the Workflow Plugin we have 3 new activity level settings.

- Allow add/remove items (Bundle)
- Allow bundle metadata edition
- Allow bundle item (subject) edition.

Comment: Good points, I'll revisit the tutorial at some point. Or maybe I'll just convince this answer's author to do a follow-up. :-)