# How do you start a Workflow on a bundle in using the Event System?

Tags: workflow, bundles

How do you start a workflow on a bundle in the Event System in Tridion 2013 SP1?

Which DLL's do I need to refer to do so?

I have created a bundle ("tcm:26-135-8192") in Tridion and I have associated a Bundle Schema with it which has a workflow.

```
Bundle bundle = (Bundle)item.Session.GetObject("tcm:26-135-8192");
bundle.AddItem(item); 
bundle.Save();

StartWorkflowInstruction instruction = new StartWorkflowInstruction(item.Session);  

instruction.Subjects.Add(bundle);  

ProcessInstance result = bundle.ContextRepository.StartWorkflow(instruction);
```

My requirement is to add items to this bundle through event system and start the workflow on this. But i am getting a Error on `bundle.Save();` which says "Item is shared".

Any suggestions?

This is what I am getting in Event Viewer . I have created this Bundle in publication 18 and I am trying to add one item in publication 26.
Should i be creating this bundle in piublication 18 as well.

The item is shared.

Component: Tridion.ContentManager
Errorcode: 0
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

StackTrace Information Details:
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.OrganizationalItem.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VirtualFolder.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Bundle.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VirtualFolder.Save()
   at MetLife.ADD.Tridion.Eventing.PageUnPublishWorkFlow.AddItemToUnPublishBundle(RepositoryLocalObject item)
   at MetLife.ADD.Tridion.Eventing.PageUnPublishWorkFlow.PageUnPublishWorkFlowChange(Page subject, UnPublishEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.EventSubscription.b__0(AsynchronousEventWorkItem workItem)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.StaThreadPool`1.StaThread.DoWork()

Comment: Can you share the entire stack trace? Also did you confirm if the bundle is not shared/localized in publication: 26 as the error says (items cannot be added/removed from a shared/localized bundle)?

Comment: I have added the event viewer trace.

Comment: As I already mentioned in my earlier comment that it is not possible to add/remove items to/from a bundle in shared/localized context. Ideally you should create the bundle at the lowest level in your blueprint where all of the items you want to add are available. **Shared/localized items can be added to bundle**.

Answer (score 4):

Use the TOM.NET API to make certain Workflow-related events in Content Manager trigger a piece of custom code you write. You can subscribe to a number of moments before, during and after a specific event.

Events related to Workflow are in the `Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.Events` namespace.

Refer to the following existing questions for more information:

- [Setting Bundle Namespace in Event System](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/setting-bundle-namespace-in-event-system)
- [How to start workflow proces for a bundle?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2071/how-to-start-workflow-proces-for-a-bundle)
- [How to configure a Bundle for workflow?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1935/how-to-configure-a-bundle-for-workflow)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to add/remove items to/from a bundle in shared/localized context. Ideally you should create the bundle at the lowest level in your blueprint where all of the items you want to add are available. Shared/localized items can be added to bundle. Then start workflow on that bundle.

```
StartWorkflowInstruction instruction = new StartWorkflowInstruction(session);
instruction.ProcessDefinition = myProcessDefinition; // Optional, otherwise it is going to use the configured task process of the bundle.ContextRepository
instruction.Subjects.Add(bundle);
ProcessInstance result = bundle.ContextRepository.StartWorkflow(instruction);
```

Comment: I got it working by creating the Bundle at lowest level.
I am able to trigger the Workflow associated to the Bundle and items added to this bundle.
I have another question here .
My actual requirement was on un-publish , I need to start the Workflow and after completion of workflow I need to unpublish it.
Do I need to Stop the un-publish in Event System  before starting the Workflow ?